# Render content of multiple pages and their descendants

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, query-posts

I'd like to expose a route to my site, `animals.example.com/book`, that shows all content of pages and descendants specified in a query parameter.

For example, if my page structure is

```
intro
pets
    dogs
    cats
farm-animals
    cows
    chickens
    sheep
wild-animals
    predators
        wolves
        coyotes
    ruminants
        deer
        rabbits
appendix
    average-weights
    faq
    common-myths
```

I would like the endpoint

`animals.example.com/book?include=[farm-animals,predators]`

to render, in order, the content of these pages:

- farm-animals
- cows
- chickens
- sheep
- predators
- wolves
- coyotes

If the query parameter is omitted, the entire site should be rendered.

What functions or queries are required to accomplish this, and where should this logic hook into WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom [query variables](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/add_query_var/) to WordPress with `add_query_var()`.

```
global $wp;
$wp->add_query_var( 'includes' );
```

Having added the query var you would check if it is passed with `get_query_var('includes')`, then you could use `WP_Query()` to get the pages (You can see the available args [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)).

If it's omitted you would simply run a query to get all children of the page.

Another nice addition would be to add the query var to the permalinks using `add_rewrite_rules`.

```
function custom_query_var() {
    global $wp;
    add_rewrite_rule( '^books/(.+)', 'index.php?pagename=books&includes=$matches[1], 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_query_var' );
```

You would need to flush these rules if you switch to a different theme.

```
function flush_custom_query_var() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_theme_switch', 'flush_custom_query_var' );
```

I haven't actually tested the rewrite rules when passing an array of parameters instead of just a single one, so it would need some alteration.